# How to force a UI update during a lengthy task on the UI thread

Tags: wpf, user-interface, mvvm

I have a window, and the window contains it's content and a "Loading" overlay as follows

```
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <!-- STUFF -->
    </Grid>
    <Rectangle Fill="White" Opacity="0.7" Visibility="{Binding VisibilityWait, Mode=TwoWay, 
    Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
</Grid>
```

My ViewModel then implements INotifyPropertyChanged and includes the property;

```
    private bool visibilityWait;
    public bool VisibilityWait
    {
        get
        {
            return visibilityWait;
        }
        set
        {
            visibilityWait = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("VisibilityWait");
        }
    }
```

I know that this is set up correctly because if I set the VisibilityWait to true in the constructor, the window displays with the "Loading" overlay as expected and vice versa... However, if i try to do this during a method e.g.;

```
private void someMethod()
{
    VisibilityWait = true;
    //... Do things
    VisibilityWait = false;
}
```

Then during the time that the program is in the "do things" section, the UI does not update to show the loading overlay.

How do I solve this issue?

EDIT: I found my own solution to this problem. See the answer below.

Comment: Can you copy the `visibility` code to the `Grid` and try the same. Does the `Grid` behave like expected? And can you set a breakpoint in the `converter` and check if it is called

Comment: The grid should remain visible at all times, it is the overlay that should only appear during loading, for that reason, the visibility code would be bad to add to the grid. It is ok, I have found a solution to my problem. Posting answer now.

Comment: @KevinWallis actually my solution did not work as expected either.

Comment: Okay have you tried the same visibility logic with another control and by clicking on a `ToggleButton`? For me it sounds like the `DataContext` is wrong

Comment: can you try the `CheckBeginInvokeOnUI` from the `Dispatcher`

Comment: @KevinWallis if i change "someFunction" to just set the visibility it works fine. I just can't get it to go 'Set the visibility => do the things => set the visibility back', Even if the "do the things" is as simple as "thread.sleep(100)"

Comment: Have you checked if some exception is happening in the method? and if the  `convert` method from the `Converter` is called?

Comment: @KevinWallis I am not using the MVVM light toolkit so i don't have the checkbegininvokeonui.. :| feel like i probably shouldnt need to.. does it help to know that all of this works if i step through the application, but once i am running it doesn't work

Comment: Okay but still the same question have you set a breakpoint to your `Converter` and checked if you step into it while the method is invoked? Also have checked the exceptions?

Comment: The breakpoint is hit in the converter. Then I press f5 and I get the desired outcome. But as soon as I try it with the breakpoint disabled the issue arises.

Comment: @KevinWallis I set the property to false, use the allowuitoupdate method, then wait for 5 seconds then set the property to true. The UI becomes unusable during the 5 seconds, as expected, but the overlay does not show. If I put a breakpoint in the converter and resume, the UI does show the overlay when i continue

Comment: Have you tried UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged

Comment: @VictoryJessie Hi, I shouldn't have to use an update source trigger as i am implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in my base class. I did try though, and it had no effect. However I believe I have solved the issue now. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @KevinWallis Thank you for trying to help, I believe I have solved the issue now. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Usually when a function is taking place, any updates to the UI are blocked until the end of the function. This is because the frame does not get pushed until the end of the function. You can force this update by calling a method like this;

```
    void AllowUIToUpdate()
    {
        DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate (object parameter)
        {
            frame.Continue = false;
            return null;
        }), null);

        Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
        //EDIT:
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
                                      new Action(delegate { }));
    }
```

EDIT: I added in an extra line to the AllowUIToUpdate function, and now everything functions as expected!

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using UI thread to do the time-consuming work, instead of doing that work in background thread? That would leave the UI thread free for updates and eliminate the need to force them this way...

Comment: This part of my project was created a long time ago before I started using background threads.. I probably could change it to do that, however I was looking for a simpler fix and I wasn't too worried if it was "hacky".. this way the user cannot use the UI while this operation is happening (Which is as desired) and can still be updated that the program is doing work.

Comment: Also, I'm sure there will be other less skilled users that will want to force UI updates instead of messing with background threads. For simpler applications especially

Comment: I solved my issue by awaiting my Task, but this solution was helpful for testing in the interim.

Comment: WPF doesn't take kindly to background threads updating view models it is observing.  You have to do some other hoops if not this one to marshal changes to the UI thread.

Answer (score 3):

#### An improvement on @Lewis_Heslop answer, this seams to work perfectly with MVVM:

```
private static void AllowUIToUpdate()
{
    DispatcherFrame frame = new();
    // DispatcherPriority set to Input, the highest priority
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate (object parameter)
    {
        frame.Continue = false;
        Thread.Sleep(20); // Stop all processes to make sure the UI update is perform
        return null;
    }), null);
    Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
    // DispatcherPriority set to Input, the highest priority
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action(delegate { }));
}
```