# WPF Force UI to update

Tags: c#, wpf

In my application user can scroll up/down MainWindow.

Problem is, that when a user scrolls down MainWindow and some controls in it are not entirely visible ( for example user scrolled down and only the bottom of the control is visible) these controls are not refreshing/updating its values (provided via binding). I suspect that WPF is detecting, that control is not visible in some way and does not bother to update UI of it. So how can I force these controls to update their UI?

For example, in picture below there is some chart in the MainWindow.But the window is small and scrolled down so the chart is not entirely visible. It does not update, it is still. When I maximize the window chart starts updating. I want it to update always, no matter how small part of it is visible:
[image]

Comment: hard to understand the issue, can you please post sample code / snapshot to understand the issue.

Comment: Sounds like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295). You should rather ask question about "not refreshing/updating" one. Consider to include relevant code ([mcve] ideally) and detailed description of the problem (what is happening and what you expect to happens instead).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force a UI update during a lengthy task on the UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787388/how-to-force-a-ui-update-during-a-lengthy-task-on-the-ui-thread)

Comment: @ManojChoudhari, I added example

Comment: Be clearer about the problem. Is a visible part not updated?  Because when it's scrolled out of sight, it is an optimization not to update.

Comment: @bommelding Yes, the visible part is not updated. In the picture I provided the chart is not updating although most of it is visible. If I make MainWindow slightly bigger it starts updating

Comment: Ok, that looks like a valid question. But add the code: XAML with databinding and the classes you bind to.

Comment: @bommelding I didn't added the code, bacause I have multiple controls ( charts, tables) and this is happening to all of them. This is not the binding issue - I have tried with empty chart ( binded properties are not changing) and I just change manually it's zoom factor. If it's completely visible it is moving, when it's partly visible it stops. It is something to do with rendering, WPF thinks that my controls are not visible so it is not rendering it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a virtualization problem, and you need to turn off virtualization for your chart (look at the chart vendor's documentation).

In the standard WPF controls there are many ways to do this.

Comment: <DataGrid EnableRowVirtualization="False"

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Unfortunately, my chart vendor (OxyPlot)  according to my research doesn't support managing virtualization.