# c# series of istruction with deley in between

Tags: c#, wpf, delay

this is a part of a program is for a robot  it have to go to a specific point  after some time to another ecc A->delay->B->delay->C

the problem is that the program does this
delay->delay->delay->Last

this is the part of the program

```
  Thread.Sleep(200);
            IK(10, 10);
            Draw(Theta1, Theta2);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            IK(11, 11);
            Draw(Theta1, Theta2);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            IK(12, 12);
            Draw(Theta1, Theta2);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            IK(13, 13);
            Draw(Theta1, Theta2);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            IK(14, 14);
            Draw(Theta1, Theta2);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            IK(15, 15);
            Draw(Theta1, Theta2);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            IK(16, 16);
            Draw(Theta1, Theta2);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            IK(17, 17);
            Draw(Theta1, Theta2);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            IK(18, 18);
            Draw(Theta1, Theta2);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            IK(19, 19);
            Draw(Theta1, Theta2);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            IK(20, 20);
            Draw(Theta1, Theta2);
```

here i have an example of what the program does

```
 Thread.Sleep(200);
 Thread.Sleep(200);
 Thread.Sleep(200);
 Thread.Sleep(200);
 Thread.Sleep(200);
 Thread.Sleep(200);
 Thread.Sleep(200);
 Thread.Sleep(200);
 Thread.Sleep(200);
 Thread.Sleep(200);
 Thread.Sleep(200);
 IK(20, 20);
 Draw(Theta1, Theta2);
```

so the robot go only to the last point  after all the time is passed

using c# & wpf

draw function

```
        public void Draw(double a,double b)
        {
            //a=t1 b=t2

            linea1.X2 = (Math.Cos((Math.PI / 180) * a)) * 100;
            linea1.Y2 = (Math.Sin((Math.PI / 180) * a)) * 100;

            linea2.X2 = (Math.Cos((Math.PI / 180) * b)) * 100;
            linea2.Y2 = (Math.Sin((Math.PI / 180) * b)) * 100;

            linea3.X2 = linea1.X2;
            linea3.Y2 = linea1.Y2;
            linea4.X1 = linea3.X2;
            linea4.Y1 = linea3.Y2;

            linea4.X2 = (Math.Cos((Math.PI / 180) * (b + a))) * 100 + linea1.X2;
            linea4.Y2 = (Math.Sin((Math.PI / 180) * (b + a))) * 100 + linea1.Y2;

        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787388/how-to-force-a-ui-update-during-a-lengthy-task-on-the-ui-thread ... may help.

Comment: you added [timer] tag. that is what you should use - a timer - and move robot on each tick. as the last resort, chech this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082221/when-to-use-task-delay-when-to-use-thread-sleep

Comment: Please provide with your Draw() method
Also, how do you state it dors this ? Output logging, other ?

Comment: i edited no you can se the draw function that  modify the coordinates of lines in a wpf canvas

Comment: You should take a look at animations. You can create a Storyboard that comprises all the animation steps

Comment: thx  so i do animation in wpf ?

Comment: [Animation Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/animation-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)