# An infinite loop in WPF C# (awaited async method calls in an endless loop)

Tags: c#, wpf, infinite-loop, coroutine

I'm trying to write a "life" game in WPF C# ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life ). I have a problem with creating a loop to write the logic of the game itself. I have a button in the MainWindow class (below):
*MainWindow.xaml.cs*

```
private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)         
        {                                                                  
            Restart.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Stop.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Start.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            Continue.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            isEvolving = true;
            Game.Evolve(theGrid);
        }
```

and there is a separate class in which the function *Game.Evolve* is written (below):

```
public static void Evolve(Grid[] grid)
        {
            Random random = new Random();

            while (MainWindow.isEvolving)
            {
                Grid square = grid[25];
                square.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(Convert.ToByte(random.Next(255)),
                    Convert.ToByte(random.Next(255)), Convert.ToByte(random.Next(255))));
            }
        }
```

This is where the infinite loop is created, which causes the program to freeze. If I understand correctly, the implementation of this game requires precisely an infinite loop, so that "Life" can evolve.

I tried creating separate functions that could be stop this one, tried creating coroutines, but if I understand correctly they don't work in WPF, tried creating separate bool variables. None of these options helped. My idea is to have a separate button (below) to stop this loop:

```
private void Stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Restart.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            Start.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            Stop.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            Continue.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            
            isEvolving = false;
        }
```

but the program just doesn't get to it, because it freezes.

Comment: If you're doing all of your work on the main thread, your game isn't going to be able to react to anything because it's stuck in the loop. You need to move your busy work to a background thread.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I would really like to do this, but I don't understand how. I tried using coroutines, but that didn't help. Can you please help with this?

Comment: `I tried using coroutines` what does that mean? What did you actually try? `await Task.Run(SomeMethod);` doesn't block the UI

Comment: You don't need a loop at all to detect events or modify UI elements either. WPF has animations and transitions built-in, which can be used to modify location, color etc. WPF elements have events that can be used to react to user actions

Comment: By far the best way to deal with the application seeming to freeze is to use a background thread as @BrootsWaymb has suggested. Another technique though would be to force a refresh of the UI at intervals in your loop - see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787388/how-to-force-a-ui-update-during-a-lengthy-task-on-the-ui-thread

Comment: The [Animation Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/animation-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) example shows how to animate the opacity of a control and associate it with a trigger event. Other pages in the same doc section show how to do the same even for styles. Instead of trying to juggle loops, threads and marshalling, you start or stop the animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can create a task running in another thread.

```
 private async void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Restart.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Stop.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Start.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        Continue.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        isEvolving = true;

        //start a new thead
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {        
            //code in the new thread
            Evolve(theGrid);
        });

    }
    public async Task Evolve(Grid[] grid)
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        while (MainWindow.isEvolving)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000); //1sec to slow evolution

            //Call the main thread to update UI
            App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {

                Grid square = grid[25];
                square.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(Convert.ToByte(random.Next(255)),
                    Convert.ToByte(random.Next(255)), Convert.ToByte(random.Next(255))));
            });

        }
    }
```

Better do not run a Task at all:

```
private async void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Restart.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    Stop.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    Start.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    Continue.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    isEvolving = true;

    await Evolve(theGrid);
}

public async Task Evolve(Grid[] grid)
{
    Random random = new Random();

    while (MainWindow.isEvolving)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000); //1sec to slow evolution

        Grid square = grid[25];
        square.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(Convert.ToByte(random.Next(255)),
        Convert.ToByte(random.Next(255)), Convert.ToByte(random.Next(255))));
    }
}
```

Comment: Task.Run and Dispatcher.Invoke are pointless here. Just call `await Evolve(...)` . Never declare `async void` methods, except event handlers.

Comment: i look at the edit,

"await Task.Run(() =>" will await the while and result as a deadlock no ?
Or it is the async on the click event that make it differ from the main thread ?

Comment: No. Be aware you have to await each async call. Never call an async method like Task.Run without awaiting it. Besides that Task.Run is entirely useless here. You should edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you also recommend some more literature to get more familiar with the threads?

Comment: @Andrew Be aware that running as Task and thus creating a thread does not make sense. `await Task.Delay(1000)` in a loop in an awaited method is enough.

Comment: @Clemens ok. I will pay attention to that, thank you.