How to update labels while a process is running?
I'm building a Desktop Application where the user scans in an ID, and it looks up information in the database, and then if the correct information is found, it then generate a pdf based on some of the said information.
All this is working as expected.
Sometimes, this takes less than 2 seconds, and sometimes it takes upwards of 30 seconds.  I have a label that tells the user to scan an ID, and when it's finished that the PDF was generated, but I want to add to it so that the label updates when the ID is found and then when it starts to generate the pdf, so that if it takes to generate the pdf, the user knows the program hasn't hung up...
This is the button click code int eh MainWindow.xaml.cs file:
        private void clkJobInfo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            >>> lblPdfInfo.Text = $"Attempting to process {txtJobID}...";
            string sJobID = txtJobID.Text;
            int iJobID = 0;
            int.TryParse(sJobID, out iJobID);

            if (iJobID == 0) {
                lblPdfInfo.Text = "Job ID is not valid.  Please scan a valid job #";
            } else {
                >>> lblPdfInfo.Text = $"Generating PDF for {txtJobID}...";
                provider = new Provider(iJobID);
                if (provider.Success) {
                    lblPdfInfo.Text = $"PDF for {provider.data.ProviderName} has printed. Scan new job when ready.";
                    txtJobID.Text = String.Empty;
                    txtJobID.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
                } else {
                    lblPdfInfo.Text = $"Problem creating pdf - {provider.FailureMessage}";
                }
            }
            
        }


The two >>> lines are what I'd like to display, but they don't do anything - the program just waits until the pdf is generated and displays the Success message.
How do I fix this so that those two update label lines work?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787388/how-to-force-a-ui-update-during-a-lengthy-task-on-the-ui-thread

The UI won't update because all the process is running on the UI thread (main thread). Unless the UI thread is released the UI can't update the changes in you label.
This doc might help.
Here let me show you a simple example:
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="IdTextBox" />
    <Button
        x:Name="RunButton"
        Click="RunButton_Click"
        Content="Run" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="MessagesTextBlock" />
</StackPanel>

private List<string> ValidIds { get; } = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

private async void RunButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Since this is a Click event handler, 
    // this will start runing on the UI thread.
    var id = IdTextBox.Text;

    MessagesTextBlock.Text = "Processing...";

    if (await ValidateId(id) is false)
    {
        MessagesTextBlock.Text = "Invalid Id";
        return;
    }

    if (await CreatePdfFromId(id) is null)
    {
        MessagesTextBlock.Text = "Error creating PDF";
        return;
    }

    MessagesTextBlock.Text = "PDF created successfully";
}

private async Task<bool> ValidateId(string id)
{
    return await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        // The UI thread will be released and
        // this will run on another thread.
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return ValidIds.Contains(id);
    });
}

private async Task<object?> CreatePdfFromId(string id)
{
    return await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        // The UI thread will be released and
        // this will run on another thread.
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return new object();
    });
}

